# Searching for a String1- Date format(latest date) and then find String 2 - Text format in a paragraph

Tags: regex

I have the following data:(In the format of - Date and String)

03/20/2014:
IMR# 12 is resolved.

03/21/2014:
The application went into production.

03/28/2014:
An issue found. IMR# 13 is raised.

---

Here, i need to pick the latest date(String 1) and look for some text(suppose IMR#)(String 2) in the data that comes after that date(String 1).

I can use regular expression to find the IMR#(String 2) but how to go to the latest date and then find the find IMR# is my quetsion. In the above mentioned data, i want to get IMR# 13 from the latest date: 03/28/2014.

Comment: Isn't the latest date `03/31/2014` though?

Comment: Sorry, i entered wrong date. I just changed it.

Comment: Okay. Well, regex isn't very suitable to do comparison between numbers, and less so dates... If there's a solution, it could very well be very complex; as in several hundreds of characters long for a single regex. Might be better to put the data in a key-value array and get the highest date (key), and then use it to get the value.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @dg99 I am using vbscript.

Comment: sorting dates can be problematic, that's why i have it in the format yyyymmdd then it'll sort the way i need regardless, unless vb has some function that'll sort dates properly.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.